# How to allocate different heap sizes to different eclipse instances?

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

In eclipse I can have multiple eclipse instances, each pointing to a different workspace.
I want one eclipse instance to have lesser `heap size` than the other, because the number of projects it handles are less and the stuff I run in it requires less memory (this can be for any reason).
I can set the heap size in `eclipse.ini` by using

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

options.
But, this changes the heap size for every eclipse instance I start. I don't want this. 
**I want different heap sizes for different eclipse instances. How do I achieve this?** (I reckon something in the .metadata folder in the workspace).

Comment: Why not use Working Sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the ini file to use with the [--launcher.ini command line option](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) when launching eclipse:

> --launcher.ini <location> (Executable)
>
> the location of the product .ini file to use.  If not specified the executable will look for a file beside the launcher with the same
>   name and the extension .ini.  (ie eclipse.exe looks for eclipse.ini,
>   product.exe looks for product.ini)

You can either create different shortcuts or different `.exe` files, e.g. for Windows use `path/to/eclipse.exe --launcher.ini eclipse-min.ini` (or copy your default `eclipse.exe` to `eclipse-min.exe`) to use a file called `eclipse-min.ini` from your eclipse installation directory (which can then contain a configuration for a smaller heap size).